# Can't delete file. File in use by another process

Tags: vb.net

I have a program (simple file updater) which downloads a file. Before that, an old version of this file is queued for deletion. But if I edit this file e.g. in text editor (save and close it), then my program refuses to delete it.

I have sub like this

```
Private Sub delete_file(ByVal dir As String)
    Try
        If My.Computer.FileSystem.FileExists(dir) Then My.Computer.FileSystem.DeleteFile(dir)
    Catch ex As Exception
        Debug.WriteLine(ex.ToString())
        Sleep(1000)
        delete_file(dir)
    End Try
End Sub
```

It never goes out of the recursion. Exception says that file is being used by other process, and waiting doesn't change anything.
Any clues?

[EDIT]
Changed Sub a bit, so it doesn't contain recursion in Exception handler

```
Private Sub delete_file(ByVal dir As String)
    Dim ok As Boolean = True
    Try
        If My.Computer.FileSystem.FileExists(dir) Then My.Computer.FileSystem.DeleteFile(dir)
    Catch ex As Exception
        Debug.WriteLine(ex.ToString())
        ok = False
    End Try

    If ok = False Then
        Sleep(1000)
        delete_file(dir)
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: This may be an option you can set in your text editor to only have a handle open to the file while it being written or read.

Comment: Also, calling into delete_file() from within the Exception handler is a _really_ bad idea. Maybe change the code to fire the task again via a Timer?

Comment: Text editor was just example. If other program edits this file (automatically) same situation occurs.

Comment: also, use of Timer won't prevent my app from going further (which sleep does), so it may behave inappropriate.

Comment: If I were to go with a timer, I'd keep a variable to maintain current state. You could then move on to the next state only when the conditions are satisfied. I'm not sure what can be done regarding the locking of the file. If something has a file handle open, Windows is going to prevent you from deleting it. I've used programs like "unlocker" to force a file release, but it's pretty brute force (read: scary), and I only use them against malicious programs (viruses, worms, etc), where I know I can't get a file lock freed.

Comment: Why are you using recursion?  Have you tried a simple while loop (with a try block inside it)?  Doing this you could also build in a safety, such as after 100 tries exit without deleting.

Answer (score 0):

Words "another process" are VERY ambiguous.

It turned out that other function from my program was opening the same file twice, and closing it only once. Fixing that removed problem with deleting it.

So when u're having the same error, try searching your program for other places when this file may be modified.

Thanks for comments, they surely gave me some hints about good programming.